# Is there a "default" way to end a contract, particularly wrt mobile phones?

Tags: contract-law, united-kingdom

[It is in the news](https://www.theguardian.com/media/2023/dec/19/i-was-cut-off-four-times-virgin-media-customers-say-its-too-hard-to-cancel-costly-contracts) that mobile phone companies are making it hard for people to cancel their contracts.  In the "old days" this would have meant a letter to the organisation cancelling the contract and a letter to the bank cancelling the payment.  The customer choosing to communicate this way would seem to avoid the possibility of the company having such control over the process as is documented in that article.

Would such a letter, perhaps to the registered head office of the company, be a legal way to cancel a contract in such a situation?

Comment: In my experience, how to cancel, and notice periods etc. are likely to be specified in the contract – there's no one answer (subject to any unfair terms legislation).

Comment: @TripeHound The notice period definitely can be specified in the contract. But I don't know whether they could specify that cancellation is only possible through their phone hotline or something like that. I would assume a signed letter is always valid regardless of what the contract says but I don't know.